# I am trying to send push notification using parse.com, and facing an unknown issue

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, push

[image]Actually I want to send notification to all the user of my application within some distance on the click of a button using `parse.com` and also I have my database in `parse.com` and for this the code, I wrote in `onClick` Method :

I updated the code as, but it also not working:

```
ParseQuery userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.whereWithinMiles("location",currentUser.getParseGeoPoint("Location"), 5.0);

// Find devices associated with these users
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereMatchesQuery("user", userQuery);

// Send push notification to query
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); 

push.setMessage("Only users near" +  currentUser.getParseGeoPoint("Location")+" will recieve this push notification");
push.sendInBackground();
```

I am getting this status page in parse.com, when I am trying to send notification to other devices

Comment: There is no log relevant to the code you are running, can you put the code in try-catch and then print the relevant log and update here.

Comment: ok sure, i will do that

Comment: it is not throwing any exception, as such but not getting the desired notifications

Comment: Ok, you have users subscribed to Everyone channel right on your Parse database?

Comment: sorry, i dont have idea about that, can u tell me how to do that?

Comment: You can go to the parse console (https://www.parse.com/apps/), Select the App where you are saving data, select the Core tab and on right side you will see the Installation table under Data tab. Make sure you have records there and channels field has Everyone entry.

Comment: Also as per the last log update, there is a lot of Connection error so make sure you have active internet connection too.

Comment: in userQuery, user is null and isRunning is False, do u have any idea about it?

Comment: is there any way to optimize this code and make it work?

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshot of the push dashboard, can you please look into it?/